# How to use Cypher to create weighted relationships from a node to an list/array of nodes?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I would like to create nodes using a list/array of relationships (from an imported CSV). Here, in the table "ID" is the node that should be linked to the list of nodes "Relationships", ultimately using "Distances" as the weights of the relationships.

```
| ID | Relationships | Distances     |
| -- | ------------- | ------------- |
| 1  | [1, 3, 5]     | [0, 0.8, 0.3] |
| 2  | [2, 3, 5]     | [0, 0.4, 0.1] |
| 3  | [3, 2, 4]     | [0, 0.2, 0.6] |
| 4  | [4, 3, 5]     | [0, 0.8, 0.6] |
| 5  | [5, 3, 4]     | [0, 0.1, 0.8] |
```

Note, the most similar (zero distance) item refers to the node itself.
A file with 100 entities can be found at:
https://github.com/SebastiaanK97/NetworkSimilarity.git

Thus far, I didn't accomplish setting the relationships to the right nodes:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///cc.csv' AS cc    
WITH cc WHERE cc.id IS NOT NULL
CREATE (n:Nodes {id:toInteger(cc.id)})
CREATE (t:Targets {ids:apoc.convert.fromJsonList(cc.Relationships)})    
WITH n, t
UNWIND t.ids as id
CREATE (t)-[:SIMILAR_TO]->(n) 
RETURN t, n
```

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can use `UNWIND` with a list of indexes using [`range`](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/list/#functions-range), and then access each of your lists (Relationships and Distances) with `[]` indexing like this:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SebastiaanK97/NetworkSimilarity/main/cc.csv' AS cc    
WITH cc WHERE cc.ID IS NOT NULL
CREATE (n:Node { id: toInteger(cc.ID) })
WITH cc, n
UNWIND range(0, size(cc.Distances)-1) as idx
WITH n, cc.Distances[idx] as dist, cc.Relationships[idx] as targetId
WHERE targetId <> n.id   // exclude relationship to "self"
CREATE (target:Node {id: targetId})
CREATE (t)-[:SIMILAR_TO {distance: dist}]->(n) 
RETURN t, n
```

However, this query is failing with your dataset due to the quotes around the lists in the CSV, which makes Cypher interpret it as a string and not a list. I've fixed it by using [`split`](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/string/#functions-split) like this:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SebastiaanK97/NetworkSimilarity/main/cc.csv' AS cc    
WITH cc WHERE cc.ID IS NOT NULL
MERGE (n:Node { id: toInteger(cc.ID) })
WITH cc, n, 
     split(cc.Relationships, ",") as rels, 
     split(cc.Distances, ",") as dists
UNWIND range(0, size(rels)-1) as idx
WITH n, dists[idx] as dist, rels[idx] as targetId
WHERE targetId <> n.id
MERGE (t:Node {id: targetId})
CREATE (t)-[:SIMILAR_TO {distance: dist}]->(n) 
RETURN t, n
```

Finally, you'll have noticed that, in order to prevent creating multiple nodes with the same ID, I've replaced your `CREATE` statements with [`MERGE`](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/). But be aware that it can lead to perf issues with large dataset due to the so-called "Eager operator". Read more about it [here](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-import-csv/#_optimizing_load_csv_for_performance) and [here](https://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2014/10/23/neo4j-cypher-avoiding-the-eager/) for instance.

Comment: Clear, thank you very much. Replacing the following removes the remainders "[", "]", " ". Yet, storing relationships differently would be the optimal solution.


UNWIND range(0, size(rels)-1) as idx
WITH n, 
     toInteger(trim(replace(replace(dists[idx], "[", ""), "]", ""))) as dist, 
     toInteger(trim(replace(replace(rels[idx], "[", ""), "]", ""))) as targetId

Comment: Good catch! Unfortunately I have not found a nicer method to convert a list in a string to a real list in Cypher.